# Android: How to detect when a scroll has ended

Tags: android, android-canvas, smooth-scrolling

I am using the onScroll method of GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener to scroll a large bitmap on a canvas. When the scroll has ended I want to redraw the bitmap in case the user wants to scroll further ... off the edge of the bitmap, but I can't see how to detect when the scroll has ended (the user has lifted his finger from the screen).

e2.getAction() always seems to return the value 2 so that is no help.
e2.getPressure seems to return fairly constant values (around 0.25) until the final onScroll call when the pressure seems to fall to about 0.13. I suppose I could detect this reduction in pressure, but this will be far from foolproof.

There must be a better way: can anyone help, please?

Comment: I've added `if (e2.getPressure() < 0.15)` to the onScroll() method. As expected this sometimes detects the end of the scroll, but not always. Surely there must be a better way!

Comment: I've now abandoned the getPressure approach. It's too unreliable. Instead I'm checking the cumulative distance scrolled and redrawing the bitmap when this exceeds a defined limit. This is more predictable, but still far from ideal. If anyone has any suggestions for a better approach I should be very pleased to hear them!

Comment: Of the many answers to this thread thosed that have proved most useful to me have been those from Akos Cz, Aron Cederholm and Mike.

Comment: Try this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181828/android-detect-when-scrollview-stops-scrolling

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem.  Hope this helps.

```
// declare class member variables
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
private OnTouchListener mGestureListener;
private boolean mIsScrolling = false;


public void initGestureDetection() {
        // Gesture detection
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            handleDoubleTap(e);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            handleSingleTap(e);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            // i'm only scrolling along the X axis
            mIsScrolling = true;                
            handleScroll(Math.round((e2.getX() - e1.getX())));
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        /**
         * Don't know why but we need to intercept this guy and return true so that the other gestures are handled.
         * https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8233
         */
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("GestureDetector --> onDown");
            return true;
        }
    });

    mGestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                return true;
            }

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(mIsScrolling ) {
                    Log.d("OnTouchListener --> onTouch ACTION_UP");
                    mIsScrolling  = false;
                    handleScrollFinished();
                };
            }

            return false;
        }
    };

    // attach the OnTouchListener to the image view
    mImageView.setOnTouchListener(mGestureListener);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Judging by the thread on Google Code Android, which your link refers to, there seems to be some confusion about the consequences of returning "true" or "false". I'll try "return true" in the onDown method and shall report back.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for this code. It seems to be the answer to my problem. I thought at first the crucial line in your code was "return true" in the onDown method, but in fact this seems to make no difference in my code. The key point seems to be that, so far as I can see, the GestureDetector is never notified of an ACTION_UP event, so as (you correctly identified) I have to include code in my onTouchListener.onTouch() method to look out for this event at the end of the scroll. Thanks again!

Comment: Interesting... and very helpful. But in a quick test I seem to be getting a touch-up event before a fling. I want to do different things if a fling is occurring or scrolling has simply stopped. When I detect a touch-up, how do I know if I'm about to get a fling event so that I won't perform my normal scroll-end functionality?

Comment: @GarretWilson You can use a VelocityTracker to detect the velocity of your motion event, which then you can use to determine if a fling is about to happen.  See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/VelocityTracker.html  and/or the following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155907/speed-or-acceleration-of-motion-event-android

Comment: to capture `ACTION_UP` in `onTouchEvent`, make sure `onFling()` return false.

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Scroller.html.
Especially this could be of help (sorted by relevance):

```
isFinished();
computeScrollOffset();
getFinalY(); getFinalX(); and getCurrY() getCurrX()
getDuration()
```

This implies that you have to create a Scroller.

If you want to use touching you could also use GestureDetector and define your own canvas scrolling. The following sample is creating a ScrollableImageView and in order to use it, you have to define the measurements of your image. You can define your own scrolling range and after finishing your scrolling the image gets redrawn.

http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=31487#31487

Depending on your code you should consider invalidating (int l, int t, int r, int b); for the invalidation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The Scroller looks as if it is designed to start a scroll in response to a Fling gesture and to continue scrolling for a distance determined by the programmer (somewhat like the Home screen on HTC phones). However, I want the screen image to move with the user's touch. I have followed ideas in the anddev thread in my app. However, so far as I can see this example only draws the buffer image once. My app has an image of potentially unlimited size which needs to be redrawn when the app is idle (after one scroll has finished and before another starts.)

Answer (score 3):

```
SimpleOnGestureListener.onFling()
```

It seems to take place when a scroll ends (i.e. the user lets the finger go), that's what I am using and it works great for me.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I'm afraid I won't have time to try it out for a few days, but I look forward to seeing if it works for me. It will be very neat if it does!

Comment: Sadly, onFling only seems to be called at the end of a quick gesture. I need to redraw, not only after a fling, but at the end of a slow precise scroll as well.

Comment: It seems onFling really gets called even after a short scroll, but not every time, e.g. if you release it slowly it doesn't. Inside the onFling you need to detect the velocity of the scroll and other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Coming back to this after a few months I've now followed a different tack: using a Handler (as in the Android Snake sample) to send a message to the app every 125 milliseconds which prompts it to check whether a Scroll has been started and whether more than 100 milliseconds has elapsed since the last scroll event.

This seems to work pretty well, but if anyone can see any drawbacks or possible improvements I should be grateful to hear of them.

The relevant the code is in the MyView class:

```
public class MyView extends android.view.View {

...

private long timeCheckInterval = 125; // milliseconds
private long scrollEndInterval = 100;
public long latestScrollEventTime;
public boolean scrollInProgress = false;

public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

private timeCheckHandler mTimeCheckHandler = new timeCheckHandler();

class timeCheckHandler extends Handler{

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (scrollInProgress && (now>latestScrollEventTime+scrollEndInterval)) {
                    scrollInProgress = false;
```

//              Scroll has ended, so insert code here

//              which calls doDrawing() method

//              to redraw bitmap re-centred where scroll ended

```
                    [ layout or view ].invalidate();
        }
        this.sleep(timeCheckInterval);
        }

        public void sleep(long delayMillis) {
            this.removeMessages(0);
            sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);
            }
    }
}

@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
```

//      code to draw large buffer bitmap onto the view's canvas
//      positioned to take account of any scroll that is in progress

```
}

public void doDrawing() {
```

//      code to do detailed (and time-consuming) drawing
//      onto large buffer bitmap

//      the following instruction resets the Time Check clock
//      the clock is first started when
//      the main activity calls this method when the app starts

```
        mTimeCheckHandler.sleep(timeCheckInterval);
}
```

//  rest of MyView class

}

and in the MyGestureDetector class

```
public class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) {

    [MyView].scrollInProgress = true;
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();  
    [MyView].latestScrollEventTime =now;

    [MyView].scrollX += (int) distanceX;
    [MyView].scrollY += (int) distanceY;
```

//      the next instruction causes the View's onDraw method to be called
//      which plots the buffer bitmap onto the screen
//      shifted to take account of the scroll

```
    [MyView].invalidate();

}
```

// rest of MyGestureDetector class

}

Comment: Although this worked OK the answer provided by Akos Cz on 29-09-2010 (see above) is much neater. Not only is the code much simpler, but it also avoids any unnecessary delay waiting for a time check. With Akos's code the end of the scroll is detected immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into this same issue. I saw Akos Cz's answer to your question. I created something similar, but with my version, I noticed that it only worked for a regular scroll - meaning one that doesn't generate a fling. But if a fling did get generated - regardless if I processed a fling or not, then it did NOT detect the "ACTION_UP" in "onTouchEvent". Now maybe this was just something with my implementation, but if it was I couldn't figure out why.

After further investigation, I noticed that during a fling, the "ACTION_UP" was passed into "onFling" in "e2" every time. So I figured that must be why it wasn't being handled in "onTouchEvent" in those instances.

To make it work for me I only had to call a method to handle the "ACTION_UP" in "onFling" and then it worked for both types of scrolling. Below are the exact steps I took to implement my app:

-initialized a "gestureScrolling" boolean to "false" in a constructor.

-I set it to "true" in "onScroll"

-created a method to handle the "ACTION_UP" event. Inside that event, I reset "gestureSCrolling" to false and then did the rest of the processing I needed to do.

-in "onTouchEvent", if an "ACTION_UP" was detected and "gestureScrolling" = true, then I called my method to handle "ACTION_UP"

-And the part that I did that was different was: I also called my method to handle "ACTION_UP" inside of "onFling".

Comment: Thanks for this very clear summary. The code I have ended up with is very similar to yours except that I have not bothered to test for ACTION_UP inside onFling ... I simply treat every onFling call (regardless of its ACTION type) as the end of a scroll (assuming that the scrolling flag is true when onFling is called) in the same way as I treat an ACTION_UP event detected in the onTouch call of the onTouchListener.

Comment: I believe every fling happens as a result of a quick scroll and an ACTION_UP, so I think you are right that there is no need to test for ACTION_UP, but just always assume every fling is the end of a scroll. Using that same logic, do you really need to test to see if the scrolling flag is true in onFling, because if I am not mistaken, you can't have a Fling without a scroll proceeding it, so I don't think you would need to check if your scroll flag is set.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right! However, I think I still need the scroll flag in order to detect (in onTouch) the end of a scroll that is too slow to be treated as a fling, so will need to keep the statement in onFling (as well as in onTouch) which sets the flag to false.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure it is too late for you, however, it seems I have found the right solution to your original question and not necessarily the intention.

If you are using Scroller/OverScroller Object for scrolling you should check the return value from the following function.

```
public boolean computeScrollOffset()
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. As I mentioned above, the Scroller looks as if it is designed to start a scroll in response to a Fling gesture and to continue scrolling for a distance determined by the programmer (somewhat like the Home screen on HTC phones). However, I want the screen image to move with the user's touch.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work as you need

```
protected class SnappingGestureDetectorListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener{
    
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY){
        boolean result = super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
        
        if(!result){
            //Do what you need to do when the scrolling stop here
        }
            
        return result;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: In theory maybe, but in practice that doesn't work as expected: you receive false even during scrolling.

Comment: SimpleOnGestureListener does always return false

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

I've enriched the existing **GestureDetector.OnGestureListener** with **onFingerUp()** method. This listener does everything as the built-in GestureDetector and it can also listen to the finger up event (it's not onFling() as this is called only when the finger is lifted up along with a quick swipe action).

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class FingerUpGestureDetector extends GestureDetector {
    FingerUpGestureDetector.OnGestureListener fListener;
    public FingerUpGestureDetector(Context context, OnGestureListener listener) {
        super(context, listener);
        fListener = listener;
    }

    public FingerUpGestureDetector(Context context, GestureDetector.OnGestureListener listener, OnGestureListener fListener) {
        super(context, listener);
        this.fListener = fListener;
    }

    public FingerUpGestureDetector(Context context, GestureDetector.OnGestureListener listener, Handler handler, OnGestureListener fListener) {
        super(context, listener, handler);
        this.fListener = fListener;
    }

    public FingerUpGestureDetector(Context context, GestureDetector.OnGestureListener listener, Handler handler, boolean unused, OnGestureListener fListener) {
        super(context, listener, handler, unused);
        this.fListener = fListener;
    }

    public interface OnGestureListener extends GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
        boolean onFingerUp(MotionEvent e);
    }

    public static class SimpleOnGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener implements FingerUpGestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFingerUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (super.onTouchEvent(ev)) return true;
        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            return fListener.onFingerUp(ev);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself but looking at onTouch() you always get a sequence 0<2>1, so the end has to be a 1 for finger lift.

Comment: Similar question for a ListView: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768391/how-to-detect-android-listview-scrolling-stopped

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added "implements OnTouchListener" to the definition of the View class, so the whole line reads 'public class MyView extends android.view.View  implements OnTouchListener {'. However, the onTouch() method never seems to be called when I tap or scroll. Does the fact that I have a separate GestureDetector class which 'extends SimpleOnGestureListener' mean that the OnTouchListener gets by-passed?

Comment: Rob Kent, I've only just seen your comment. So far as I can see the OnScrollListener is only available for a ListView. I'm working with a drawing Canvas on a View that 'extends android.view.View'. Do you know if there's a way I can use an OnScroll method with this (other than the GestureListener I'm already using)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Android, but looking at the documentation it seems Rob is right: [Android ACTION_UP constant](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP) Try checking for ACTION_UP from getAction()?

Edit: What does e1.getAction() show? Does it ever return ACTION_UP? The documentation says it holds the initial down event, so maybe it'll also notify when the pointer is up

Edit: Only two more things I can think of. Are you returning false at any point? That may prevent ACTION_UP

The only other thing I'd try is to have a seperate event, maybe onDown, and set a flag within onScroll such as isScrolling. When ACTION_UP is given to onDown and isScrolling is set then you could do whatever you want and reset isScrolling to false. That is, assuming onDown gets called along with onScroll, and getAction will return ACTION_UP during onDown

Comment: Yes, I've tried checking getAction() but it always returns 2 when onScroll is called. The only "up" event that is recognised by onGestureListener is onSingleTapUp; this is not returned at the end of a Scroll.

Comment: But in this code they listen for ACTION_UP within onScroll of a SimpleOnGestureListener: http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/source/browse/trunk/connectbot/src/org/connectbot/Console.java?r=54

Comment: Thanks, Bob. This is a mystery. I've inserted `Log.i("onScroll", Integer.toString(e2.getAction()));` as the first statement in onScroll and LogCat just shows a string of "2"'s when I scroll. If I put the Log statement after `if(e2.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)` nothing is logged in LogCat even when I end the scroll.

Comment: Sorry, just trying to eliminate possibilities here. See my edit above

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestions. Unfortunately, e1.getAction() returns only 0.

Comment: Alright, with those last two suggestions I'm out of ideas. Sorry I can't be more helpful

Comment: My onScroll code returns 'false'. I've tried changing this to 'true' but e2.getAction() still always returns 2 and e1.getAction() still returns 0. How might returning 'true' help? The Android reference says that 'true' should be returned if the event is consumed, so doesn't 'true' prevent any further action in response to the touch/scroll? I'll have a look at your onDown suggestion ...

Comment: I've added code for onDown(), but all I see in LogCat is a single 0 from onDown followed by 2's from onScroll, so I can't see how this could help, I'm afraid. Thanks very much for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

i have not tried / used this but an idea for an approach:

**stop / interrupt redrawing canvas on EVERY scroll event wait 1s and then start redrawing canvas on EVERY scroll.**

this will lead to performing the redraw only at scroll end as only the last scroll will actually be uninterrupted for the redraw to complete.

hope this idea helps you :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I don't think it will help me. I don't want to interrupt the redrawing because I want to scroll smoothly. My approach to this is to do the detailed drawing to a buffer bitmap then in the onDraw() method to plot this bitmap onto the View's canvas. During the course of the Scroll I replot the bitmap shifted slightly to reflect the scroll. What I want to do is detect when the Scroll has ended so that I can redraw the buffer bitmap (which is time-consuming) ready for the next scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Extract from the onScroll event from GestureListener API: [link text](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html)

> public abstract boolean onScroll
>   (MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float
>   distanceX, float distanceY) Since: API
>   Level 1
>
> **Returns
>       * true if the event is consumed, else false**

Perhaps once the event has been consumed, the action is finished and the user has taken their finger off the screen or at the least finished this onScroll action

You can then use this in an IF statement to scan for  == true and then commence with the next action.

Comment: Thanks for this. Are you suggesting that my code should call the onScroll method and check what it returns. If so, I'm not sure how to do this. I thought that it was a method called by the system to run code inserted by me. I was puzzled by the word "returns" in the documentation, but assumed that they meant to say "return" ... in other words my code should return true at the end of the method if the event had been consumed and false otherwise. Can you clarify for me, please?

Comment: Use the return from the touch event as a cue for when the finger has been lifted! When the function returns true the event has finished. So using it in an: If(onScroll == True) { DoThis(); } Else { EffectErrorHandler();} and viola!

Comment: Thanks for your further comment, Blue. I'm afraid I still don't understand what you mean. The onScroll() method is an over-ridden method of OnSimpleGestureListener (it is a method of a class which "extends" SimpleOnGestureListener) and is called by the Android system when a finger is dragged across the screen. How do I call it? Where in my code should I put the call? What arguments should I provide?

Comment: The Android Reference for SimpleOnGestureListener is confusing: the section for OnScroll says that the method "returns
true if the event is consumed, else false" but the Class Overview says the class "does nothing and return false for all applicable methods".

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at adding additional functionality to the gesture detector. Hope it helps someone put his time to better use... [gist](https://gist.github.com/WildOrangutan/043807ddbd68978179b7cea3b53c71e8)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `SimpleGestureDetector` to handle your scroll events, you can do this

```kotlin
fun handleTouchEvents(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    if(event.action == ACTION_UP) yourListener.onScrollEnd()
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
}
```