# How to detect that the HorizontalScrollView has reached an end

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

i want when reach to end ,the right button will change color ,when reach to the begin,the left button will change color ,so ,i want to ask how to  detect that the HorizontalScrollView has reached an end.

Comment: This Link will help you:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089552/android-how-to-detect-when-a-scroll-has-ended][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089552/android-how-to-detect-when-a-scroll-has-ended

Comment: [this post might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3952629/593709)

Comment: maxScrollX = horizontalScrollView.getChildAt(0) 
                   .getMeasuredWidth()-horizontalScrollView.getMeasuredWidth();
if (horizontalScrollView.getScrollX()==0) {
     lImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.left_green);
    }else {
     lImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.left);
    }
    if (horizontalScrollView.getScrollX()==maxScrollX) {
     rImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.right_green);
    }else {
     rImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.right);
    }

Answer (score 12):

```
    maxScrollX = horizontalScrollView.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredWidth()-horizontalScrollView.getMeasuredWidth(); 
    if (horizontalScrollView.getScrollX() == 0) { 
        lImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.left_green); 
    } else { 
        lImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.left); 
    }

    if (horizontalScrollView.getScrollX() == maxScrollX) { 
        rImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.right_green); 
    } else { 
        rImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.right); 
    }
```

Comment: where to fire this event - any listener for it?

Comment: you can call it in `horizontalScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener{ ... }`