# How to make button invisible when end of the list is reached in android

Tags: android, button, scrollview, actionlistener, horizontalscrollview

I am using HorizontalScrollView to display list of items to user. I want to make two buttons at both ends of list to indicate if there are items remaining on its respective side. So the button must disappear after end of the list is reached on its side. How to invoke this type of behavior in button.

Comment: Two options: you can make the button transparent or you can make its height equal to 0dp.

Comment: But my buttons and HorizontalScrollView are different views. How do I pass a message to buttons each time when a scrolling take place in HorizontalScrollView

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AlphaAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AlphaAnimation.html)

just set the Animation on the Button and start it when u reach the end

[AlphaAnimtion Example](http://tsicilian.wordpress.com/2012/04/26/android-special-effects-alpha-animation/)

Update :

[ScrollView Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597943/how-to-detect-that-the-horizontalscrollview-has-reached-an-end)

Comment: But my buttons and HorizontalScrollView are two different views. How do I pass a message to buttons each time when a scrolling take place in HorizontalScrollView?

Comment: do u want the arrows to disappear when u reach the last item or something else?