# speed or acceleration of motion event android

Tags: android, performance, touch, velocity, acceleration

Is it possible to get the speed or velocity or acceleration of touch event in android with the existing api? I have gone through MotionEvent class and none of the fields in that class seem to retrieve information that i need. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: MotionEvents don't track accelerometer events:
see here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html You need to get an instance of SensorManager for accelerometer events There's a great example here:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/a-quick-tutorial-on-coding-androids-accelerometer/472

Comment: I think he don't mean accelerometer.

Comment: Yes, i dont mean accelerometer. What i meant was speed or velocity of gesture

Answer (score 14):

MotionEvent does not help you in this case. You can use VelocityTracker class. It gets MotionEvent instances and calculates velocity of recent touch events.
You can take a look at its documentation here: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/VelocityTracker.html

First you have to get an instance by obtain() method:

```
VelocityTracker velocity = VelocityTracker.obtain();
```

then you can add ACTION_MOVE events to its queue:

```
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
    {
        velocity.addMovement(event);
    }
```

then you can compute velocity and extract x_velocity and y_velocity

```
velocity.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
float x_velocity = velocity.getXVelocity();
float y_velocity = velocity.getYVelocity();
```

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate velocity manually between each two events using `System.nanoTime`. Same way for acceleration (but using velocity instead of coordinates this time).