# Detect if listview is out of bounds and passing new item in it

Tags: android, listview, adapter, gesture, swipe-gesture

Can somebody advise how can I detect if the listview swipes out of bounds? I have only one item in the listview. And I need to detect when user swipes it up or down and listview accordingly goes up or down and show empty space above or below it. And in this moment I should to update my listview's adapter and pass new item there.

I tried to implement it with GestureListener like this :

```
 class MyGestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener implements OnTouchListener
        {

        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent arg0) {
            InteractionsAdapter adapter = new InteractionsAdapter(InteractionsActivityAlt.this,
                    R.layout.interactions_item, DashboardActivityAlt.messagesExport,DashboardActivityAlt.messagesExport.size()-2);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.i("asd","sdas");
            return true;
        }
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            if(Math.abs(e1.getY()-e2.getY()) > 250) 
                return false;               
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > 120// && Math.abs(velocityX) > 200
                    ){

              //mSwipeDetected = Action.RL;
              Log.d("one", "Coords: x=" + e1.getX() + ",y=" + e2.getY());
                //do something...
             return true;
            }
            else if(e2.getX() - e1.getX() > 120// && Math.abs(velocityX) > 200
                    ){

            // mSwipeDetected = Action.LR;
               Log.d("two", "Coords: x=" + e1.getX() + ",y=" + e2.getY());
                //do something...
             return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
             AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(InteractionsActivityAlt.this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure to choose timezone  "+"  ?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        }
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float arg2,
                float arg3) {


            float pos = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            if (pos < -170 & pos > -200)
            {


                mSwipeDetected = Action.BT;

                try {

                    Log.i("gesturelistener", "Move down");
                } 

            catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            if (pos > 170 & pos < 200)
            {

                mSwipeDetected = Action.BT;

                try {

                    Log.i("gesturelistener", "Move up");
                } 

            catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            return true;
        }
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

         public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me)
         {

         return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(me);
         }
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            if (arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                arg0.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            return false;
        } 
        }
```

It detects swipe up or down actions but not when listview goes out of bounds and show empty space.

Comment: can't you use scroll view? , it think it performs the same work.

Comment: maybe, but I need to detect when user swipes the screen when it is in the bottom of the listview and when empty space above or below the listview is showing...

Comment: i hope this will help http://stackoverflow.com/q/2089552/1643325

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! The  onDoubleTap() method gave me the solution!

Comment: happy to help...can you raise the comment as useful..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue with the method:

```
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
   return true;
}
```