# How to hook into Android ScrollView when it starts/ends scrolling?

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-scroll

How do I programmatically hook into an Android `ScrollView` when it starts/ends scrolling? I have a custom `View` which is placed inside a `ScrollView`. I want my custom `View` to be informed right before the scrolling begins and just after the scrolling ends to execute some arbitrary code.

*Note: I'm coming from iOS development and basically I'm looking for the Android equivalent of `UIScrollViewDelegate`.*

Comment: THere is example how to detect when a scroll has ended:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089552/android-how-to-detect-when-a-scroll-has-ended

Answer (score 0):

For achieveing this, you need to create a Custom scrollview by inheriting from scrollview.

Check below link. It will help you :

[Synchronise ScrollView scroll positions - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948934/synchronise-scrollview-scroll-positions-android)

[Android: Detect when ScrollView stops scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181828/android-detect-when-scrollview-stops-scrolling)