# Android - Detect when imageview or layout appear no screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have an activity that gets data from a web service. The output of the web service consists of multiple sets of one web URL and some text. The URL points to an image. Each set is displayed by creating a linear layout which contains an imageview and textview. So, for 200 sets, I would have 200 layouts, 200 imageviews, and 200 textiews. I know that a list view would be a better solution, but I've gone too far in the project to change this now.

Currently,  I download all images before the activity is displayed. I download around 200 images and in the future this might rise to more than 1000.
I would like to download the images only when the imageview appears on screen. The approach I am thinking of is creating some listener or event so that once the the imageview or layout appears on screen, the download starts. I searched a lot for this but could not find a good solution. **My problem is creating the listener not starting the download.**

Some solutions suggested lazy load but this would still mean all images are loaded which would not be appropriate for users who have limited download capacity.

Edit: I do not want to load all images, only the ones that appear on screen. And every time the user scrolls, the new imageview that appear on screen also start downloading.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lazy load of images in ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Comment: @rkmax, the solution you posted uses lazy load. I do not want to load all images, only the ones that appear on screen. And when the user scrolls down, the new imageviews that appear will start loading their images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a different and easier approach by following @Akos's solution on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089552/android-how-to-detect-when-a-scroll-has-ended) for detecting the end of the scroll view. Once the activity starts, I load 10 layouts. Once the scroll view reaches the end, I display a progress dialog and load 10 more layouts.