# How to detect onScroll end in GestureDetector?

Tags: android, scroll, gesture

I have a `GestureDetector` with a `SimpleOnGestureListener` and I provide an implementation of the onScroll method. When the scroll ends I want to start an animation. I can't simply detect `event.getAction() == ACTION_UP` because on the activity I have others gesture detectors and I don't want the animation always starts, but only if the scrolling is ended (and not, for example, when a singleTap is ended).

Comment: You could achieve this as explained in the reference link [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089552/android-how-to-detect-when-a-scroll-has-ended).

Comment: @Viren  Thanks, answer by Akos Cz is very clean and useful!

Comment: plase upvote the comment if it is usefull