# Hide fast scroll indicator from Listview in android

Tags: android

I have searched over this a lot and tried every thing 
i added this to the class

```
translator_list.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

and this is the layout for the listview

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/translator_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search_authrs"
    android:divider="@drawable/authors_menu_divider"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/sidemenu_selector"
    android:paddingRight="40dip"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

But the fast scroll still appears I enabled it cause i have an indexing function for the list and I need fastscroll
It dosen't show in kitkat but any sdk <4.4 it shows this big grey square 
![Like this image] http://blog.matto1990.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/dispay_problem.png "Like this image"

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want to remove the fast scroll? In that case just set `fastScrollEnabled` to false.

Comment: I need the fast scroll but i want to hide the indicator

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:fadeScrollbars` ( if you're API level 5 ) OR try to use `setOnScrollListener` to check scroll status and hide/show the bars .

setOnScrollListener [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852081/autohide-scrollbars-when-not-scrolling-in-a-listview).

For later versions like KITKAT,

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    view.setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(true);
}
```

This will enable it all the time.