# OnScrollListener.onScroll() called on item click in a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView with an `OnScrollListener` and an `OnItemClickListener`. When I click on an item, both the `onScroll()` method in the `OnScrollListener` and the `OnItemClickListener` are fired.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour? If not, how can I tell, inside `onScroll()`, if the user is really scrolling or he's just clicking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `onScrollStateChanged` should also be called with scrolling. Then you should be able to see if the state is idled or scrolling through the [constants](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html#SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) defined in `OnScrollListener`. 
Check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768391/how-to-detect-android-listview-scrolling-stopped) for an example.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to detect the start of the scrolling action by checking scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL.